# Google Closure Compiler: default CompilerOptions

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

In the source code, the Class CompilerOptions is used to control the compilation process. We can manually configure the options by calling "setXXX()" methods, such as "foldConstants" and "removeDeadCode". So what is the default options of the latest released closure compiler ? Can anyone list all the activated options, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The options are set based on a combination of factors. The primary 2 being the `--compilation_level` and `--warning_level` flags.

### Compilation Level

The defaults are set in the aptly named [CompilationLevel.java](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java) file. The default compilation level is `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

### Warning Level

The defaults are set in the aptly named [WarningLevel.java](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/WarningLevel.java) file.